# Cannot deploy JavaEE application to Glassfish 4.1

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ejb

I am using Netbeans 8.1, MySQL Server, Glassfish 4.1, Eclipselink as JPA-provider, Jersey as JAX-RS provider and tried to deploy the following simple procedure:

- Setup of Glassfish 4.1 with a MySQL connection pool and a data source
- Generated a standard JavaEE application with EJB and WAR module
- Added some @Entity annotated classes
- Added a persistence.xml to the ejb- and war-projects
- Auto-generated RESTful classes from my entity classes by Netbeans 8.1

The project builds just fine. But when trying to deploy the ear file to the Glassfish 4.1 Application Server I get the following error message in the console:

```
GlassFish Server 4.1, deploy, Can not read HTTP response, caught IOException, false
/Users/nicolas/Workspace (Java)/TestProject/nbproject/build-impl.xml:332: The module has not been deployed.
See the server log for details.
```

And on Glassfish log I read the following:

```
Exception while preparing the app : Unable to load the EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB. Check the archive to ensure correct packaging for /Users/nicolas/Workspace (Java)/OilImperium/dist/gfdeploy/TestProject/TestProject-war_war. If you use EJB component annotations to define the EJB, and an ejb or web deployment descriptor is also used, please make sure that the deployment descriptor references a Java EE 5 or higher version schema, and that the metadata-complete attribute is not set to true, so the component annotations can be processed as expected java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load the EJB module. DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB. Check the archive to ensure correct packaging for /Users/nicolas/Workspace (Java)/TestProject/dist/gfdeploy/TestProject/TestProject-war_war. If you use EJB component annotations to define the EJB, and an ejb or web deployment descriptor is also used, please make sure that the deployment descriptor references a Java EE 5 or higher version schema, and that the metadata-complete attribute is not set to true, so the component annotations can be processed as expected 
at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.prepare(EjbDeployer.java:190) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925) 
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepareBundle(EarDeployer.java:309) 
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.access$200(EarDeployer.java:88) 
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:155) 
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer$1.doBundle(EarDeployer.java:152) 
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnBundles(EarDeployer.java:232) 
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllTypedBundles(EarDeployer.java:241) 
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.doOnAllBundles(EarDeployer.java:270) 
at org.glassfish.javaee.full.deployment.EarDeployer.prepare(EarDeployer.java:152) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.prepareModule(ApplicationLifecycle.java:925) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:434) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219) 
at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:539) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:534) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:565) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:556) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1464) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:109) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1846) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1722) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:189) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459) 
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565) 
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Furthermore, the @Entity classes seem not to be found by the war-project:

```
Class [ ch/baumgardt/model/Well ] not found. Error while loading [ class service.WellFacadeREST ]
```

... and more:

```
Class [ ch/baumgardt/model/Player ] not found. Error while loading [ class service.PlayerFacadeREST ]
```

Somebody any ideas what I might doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

May be your server not giving access to the netbeans . Test it with working .war file to see server give the same error .

Answer (score 0):

> Restart the Glassfish and clean war and WEB_INF/lib folder becuse some time its happen .
>   [`Please Check out](https://java.net/jira/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/GLASSFISH-10592/GLASSFISH-10592.html)
>   Or you can Create Restful webservices with help of netbeans .
>   Create a java package then
>   Right-click the CustomerDB node and choose New > Other > Web Services > RESTful Web Services from Database. The New RESTful Web Service wizard opens, on the Database Tables panel.
>   i hope its help

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already use JDK 8 and GF 4.1 and I tried your suggestions, but still the same problem...

Comment: Thanks for your update. That snippet of text which you posted is exactly from the tutorial I have worked through. But the problem seems to be either in Netbeans or Glassfish...